# PUT-ing a form to update a row, but I can't find the id. Where is it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**How should I be passing in the ID?**

Error:

> Couldn't find Product without an ID

Form:

```
<% form_for :product, @product, :url => { :action => :update } do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :names %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :names %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit 'Update' %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Controller (for /products/edit/1 view):

```
def edit
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
end
```

Controller (to change the db):

```
def update
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.update_attributes(params[:product])
        format.html { redirect_to(@product, :notice => 'Product was successfully updated.') }
        format.xml  { head :ok }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @product.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the :product from the form_for statement

**Edit:** Try removing the url option also. The issue is that the URL which you are posting to does not have an id attribute.

Comment: That leads to the "No action responded to 1. Actions: create, edit, index, new, show, and update" problem"

Comment: Try then adding a :id=> @product.id to your URL hash.

Also, are you using map.resources in your routes?

Comment: the { :id => ... } works. But do I really have to put that in there? I feel like if I passed in the @product w/ all the identifying data, Rails must supply the id for me. And yeah, map.resources is done in routes.

Comment: What version of Rails are you using?

Answer (score 2):

This form tag should be sufficent:

```
<% form_for @product do |f| %>
```

Make sure you have this line in your config/routes.rb:

```
map.resources :products
```

For extra credit, you can simplify loading the @product in your controller with a `before_filter`:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :load_product, :only => [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  def load_product
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the extra credit section! That's awesome. Always looking for that.